# How to get Previous Visited Page Information

Tags: customization, custom-field, permalinks, navigation, id

I want to Change for Customized my Contact Form based on Previous URL Visited or We ca say I want to Dynamically Change the Values of Contact Form based on Previous URL Visited.

So I had searched and tried various best possible option to customized it like Session, Cookies, Global Variable, wp_get_referer, HTTP_REFERER & url_to_postid but it didn't help me.

So I am looking for Previous Visited Page ID or Custom Field Values of Previous Visited Page.

Help Please.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why those options didn't suit your needs?

Comment: Actually I want to serve dynamic content as there is not so much use of it so I am trying it via only code rather then installing special plugin for it.

But whenever i am trying to get id of previous visited page I am getting only 0. ( I want page id because i can get custom field value of that page or category) so based on that i can customized my form.